# Most efficient way to write a number in a file in C?

Tags: c, string, file-io, char, int

I need to keep trace of an int number greater than 255 in a file. It is greater than the largest unsigned char and so the use of the `fputc` seems to be not reliable (*first question: is it always true?*).
I could use `fputs`, by converting the digits in characters, so obtaining a string; but in the program i need the number as an int too!
So, the question in the title: what is so the most efficient way to write that number? Is there any way to avoid the conversion to string?
Keep that the file should then be readed by another process, where char number should become an int again.

Comment: Just write it as binary data using fwrite.

Comment: Is there any reason not to write a binary 16-bit int?

Comment: you can use unions, although it's a bit of a overkill.

Comment: Actually writing and reading the file will be two orders of magnitude slower than the fprintf/fscanf code to convert to and from a string. You're very likely to be optimising prematurely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write out the binary representation:

```
int fd;
...
int foo = 1234;
write (fd, &foo, sizeof(foo));
```

(and add error handling).

Or if you like `FILE*`

```
FILE *file;
...
int foo = 1234;
fwrite (&foo, sizeof(foo), 1, file);
```

(and add error handling).

Note that if your file is to be loaded on a different system, potential with different endianness, you might want to ensure the endianness of the bytes is constant (e.g. most significant byte or least significant byte first). You can use `htnol`, `htons` etc. for this if you want. If you know the architecture that is loading the file is the same as that saving it, there is no need for this.

Comment: The second write should be fwrite

Comment: by error handling you mean to control the value returned by write() or other?

Comment: By error handling means that you should always consider what happens if your write to the file fails. This will be in the returned value of `write` or `fwrite`.

Comment: Yes the architecture is the same, but the functions could anyway be useful.

Comment: Also, paying attention to endianness is not enough: in case of signed integer types, representation (2's complement, 1's complement, sign+magnitude) also matters.

Comment: @H2CO3 fair comment (`htonl` and friends are unsigned), but that said, I've never operated on a platform which has signed integers other than in 2s complement format *and* a POSIX network library. Now floating point it a different story...